# Multiple locales / bundles in one view

Tags: jsf-2, internationalization, bundle

We have a UI in **JSF 2.0** that is divided in two parts: one is in the user locale, and the other in a chosen locale. By example, if the user is a french guy who decides to choose english, some components of the page are in french, some others are in english.

Is it possible to achieve this?

The simple `f:loadBundle` doesn't accept any locale and use the one defined in its parent `f:view`, so it seems we can only define one locale per view.

Maybe we can use multiple `f:view`? We tried a bit and the server didn't complain that much, but the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html) says that f:view is "Container for *all* JavaServer Faces core and custom component actions used *on a page*", so I don't guess it should be safe to do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible through the `<f:loadBundle>` means. You can indeed have only one locale throughout the entire view and it's not allowed to nest `<f:view>` tags (technically it will work, but the nested tag will just be ignored).

Your best bet is to create a managed bean which extends `ResourceBundle`, wraps the bundle in the desired locale and delegates the calls to it. Something like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BundleBean extends ResourceBundle {

    private ResourceBundle wrapped;

    public BundleBean() {
        // You can get/supply the locale as a parameter or property.
        // Again, just a basic kickoff example.
        wrapped = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.i18n.text", new Locale("fr"));
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return wrapped.getObject(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return wrapped.getKeys();
    }

}
```

You can use it the usual way:

```
#{bundleBean.someKey}
#{bundleBean['some.key.with.periods']}
```

Comment: I thought about a `Bean` which contains a `ResourceBundle`, but making it _extends_ `ResourceBundle` is really clever, as it clearly simplify its use in JSF pages. 

By the way, what allow us here to do calls like `#{myBean.someKey}` even if the bean doesn't have an explicit `getSomeKey()` method? Is it something special from `ResourceBundle`?

Comment: That's correct. `ResourceBundle` has special treatment by [`ResourceBundleELResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ResourceBundleELResolver.html).

Comment: Well that would perfectly do the job we need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the English values in the default resource bundle (the one without the a suffix)? That way, it'll get displayed if there is no matching string for the current locale.

Comment: That's not exactly what the OP is asking: *"that is divided in two parts: one is in the user locale, and the other in a chosen locale"*. I'd imagine it to be part of some kind of backend admin screen.

Comment: I agree with @BalusC, whom answer fits.